# Get the last index/value from a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm  trying to get the last value within my listbox, so the user is able to enter number into the listbox. And I want to be able to output to a label text, what that value is. So it would show the last index from the listbox. Although, its just outputting the index number, -1.

```
if (lstHoldValue.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
{
 label1.Text =  Convert.ToString(this.lstHoldValue.SelectedIndex = this.lstHoldValue.Items.Count - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last item you use `lstHoldValue.Items[lstHoldValue.Items.Count - 1]` and together with a check *(to see if the listbox has at least one item, before we execute code in the if statement)* it will look like this:

```
if (lstHoldValue.Items.Count > 0)       
{
    label1.Text = lstHoldValue.Items[lstHoldValue.Items.Count - 1].ToString();
}
```